NU1100 error message when using .NET6.0 and System.Device.Gpio
I’m developing c# code for my UP board (x86/Intel Atom) to interface with GPIOs and SPI and am having an issue with System.Device.Gpio, installed as tha Nuget package under VS2022 community, when running under .NET6. Even though I’m running under the required .NET 6 runtime/SDK, a System.PlatformNotSupportedException occurs every time an instance of GpioController is called when I run the code in debug mode. The code builds with no errors however. The exception stated that

for the Windows10Driver to be used the application needs to target .NET6 with minimum Windows 10.0.17763.0.

I edited the project file to target 10.0.17763.0. On rebuilding the solution after editing the project file, the following NU1100 error was flagged:

Unable to resolve ‘Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref (=10.0.17763.34) for ‘net6.0-windows10.0.17763’. PackageSourceMapping is enabled , the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org.

It’s not clear to me what needs to be edited in the project file to overcome this issue, I would appreciate some help on this, as my UP board is completely useless until I can get this resolved.
I have searched for alternative c# drivers to System.Device Gpio  but it appears there aren’t any, so I need to get System.Device.Gpio, which wraps the libgpiod library, as far as I understand, to work.

”I edited the project file to target 10.0.17763.0” - can you edit your question to show how? The error message says it can’t find an SDK, but that’s a Windows OS version

Did you install SDK 10.0.17763.0 or greater?

Side note: Your Up board is not useless, it may run Linux, for example. There everything works fine (with GPIO and SPI).

Hi thanks everyone, in answer to the first question (https://stackoverflow.com/users/43846/stuartd), I modified the project file to target 10.0.177630.0, here is the line of code net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0  .

In answer to the second question (thankyou https://stackoverflow.com/users/16764520/minxin-yu-msft) yes I did install SDK 10.0.17763.0. Any ideas why it's not working?

In answer to the third (thankyou https://stackoverflow.com/users/2511795/0andriy) I did manage to get gpio's on the Up board working in Linux, but have only tested so far with "Echo". I'm actually in the process of developing a small spectrum analyser/tracking generator and I thought c# would be the best way forward (I like the graphics on Microsoft forms), I can't get SPI to work though.  Seems that you have an Up board, I suggest we somehow keep in contact - you can find me on facebook (Paul Clements - vampire in Transylvania) would be most happy to share my code with you. Thankyou again

When wanting to notify users in the comments, use @username notation. I don't use Facebook, sorry, but I have UP board available, indeed (I run exclusively Linux on it).
